# How to divide a column into multiple, based on another column value?

Tags: pandas, apache-spark-sql, pyspark

I need split one column into 4, based on another column values in python/pyspark.
I tried filtering it based on code and joining the multiple df's.
Is there a better way of doing this ?

```
Code   score ID

AAA     12  ABCD
BBB     14  ABCD
CCC     16  ABCD
DDD     67  ABCD
AAA     89  XYZ
BBB     65  XYZ
CCC     19  XYZ
DDD     56  XYZ


ID          score_AAA   score_BBB   score_CCC   score_DDD

ABCD            12          14      16              67
XYZ             89          65      19              56
```

Comment: How can someone suggest a "better" way, if you do not post your "current" way? Can you please show the code that you have tried?

Comment: Do you want a pandas answer or a sparksql answer?  Please review [ask]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to pivot Spark DataFrame?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30244910/how-to-pivot-spark-dataframe)

Answer (score 2):

Use `pivot`:

```
df = df.pivot(index='ID', columns='Code')
df.columns = df.columns.get_level_values(0) + '_' + df.columns.get_level_values(1)
```

Result:

```
      score_AAA  score_BBB  score_CCC  score_DDD
ID                                              
ABCD         12         14         16         67
XYZ          89         65         19         56
```

Comment: @harvpan : I mentioned using 'filter' and forming multiple dataframes and performing the join..

Comment: @rd90080 If this answer helps then mark it as an accepted solution.