# Parallelize Spark Collect Function

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I've noticed that spark's function, `collect` is extremely slow on large sets of data so I'm trying to fix this using parallelize.

My main method creates the spark session and passes that to the `get_data` func.

```
def main():
    spark = SparkSession.builder.appName('app_name').getOrCreate()
    return get_data(spark)
```

Here is where I try to parallelize my collect function

```
def get_data(spark):
    df = all_data(spark)
    data = spark.sparkContext.parallelize(df.select('my_column').distinct().collect())
    return map(lambda row: row['my_column'], data)
```

This does not work and returns this error:

> TypeError: 'RDD' object is not iterable

Does anyone have any ideas on how to parallelize or increase performance on the `get_data` function.

Comment: There is no way to parallelize a `collect` operation. It is by definition a method that serializes your data through the master node. Don't try to `collect` large amounts of data- let Spark handle the heavy lifting and only collect aggregated results.

Comment: @pault so how would you handle this if I need the `collect` so that I can map over the data?

Comment: @pault to provide some additional context, I'm trying to put the row values in some sort of a list/array so that I can pass them as values to the pyspark `pivot` function.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30244910/how-to-pivot-spark-dataframe

Comment: @ChaseHardin - if you have a fixed list that doesn't change you can ```broadcast``` that list and pass it into the ```.pivot("col", list_variable)```.  if your list is dynamic (i have faced this challenge) the only way i know is running a ```collect()``` with a ```flatMap``` to flatten into a list and then ```broadcast```

Comment: @thePurplePython, unfortunately, it's a dynamic list. How is the `flatMap` more performant than an original `map` function? Do you have an example of `broadcast` with the `pivot`?

Comment: @thePurplePython, do you have cluster configurations that work well when working with large data sets and pivots? Mainly thinking worker/driver types.

Comment: @ChaseHardin - provided an example below; cluster configurations mostly depend on the cluster hardware specs and cluster manager

Answer (score 2):

Here are examples of *static* and *dynamic* approaches using a `broadcast` variable (*read-only variable persisted in each executor memory; avoids transferring a copy of the list on the driver machine for every distributed task*) to retrieve the distinct values of a column.  Also, if you don't provide a hard-coded value during the `pivot` it will trigger an **extra** job (wide transformation shuffle) to get the distinct values for that column.

***Disclaimer => there may be a better alternative out there performance wise for the dynamic approach***

```py
print(spark.version)
2.4.3

import pyspark.sql.functions as F

# sample data
rawData = [(1, "a"),
           (1, "b"),
           (1, "c"),
           (2, "a"),
           (2, "b"),
           (2, "c"),
           (3, "a"),
           (3, "b"),
           (3, "c")]

df = spark.createDataFrame(rawData).toDF("id","value")

# static list example
l = ["a", "b", "c"]
l = spark.sparkContext.broadcast(l)

pivot_static_df = df\
  .groupby("id")\
  .pivot("value", l.value)\
  .agg(F.expr("first(value)"))

pivot_static_df.show()
+---+---+---+---+
| id|  a|  b|  c|
+---+---+---+---+
|  1|  a|  b|  c|
|  3|  a|  b|  c|
|  2|  a|  b|  c|
+---+---+---+---+

# dynamic list example
v = df.select("value").distinct().rdd.flatMap(lambda x: x).collect()
v = spark.sparkContext.broadcast(v)

print(v.value)

pivot_dynamic_df = df\
  .groupby("id")\
  .pivot("value", l.value)\
  .agg(F.expr("first(value)"))

pivot_dynamic_df.show()
['c', 'b', 'a']
+---+---+---+---+
| id|  a|  b|  c|
+---+---+---+---+
|  1|  a|  b|  c|
|  3|  a|  b|  c|
|  2|  a|  b|  c|
+---+---+---+---+
```