# How to transform a long DF into wide DF pyspark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a data frame as below:

```
df = sqlContext.createDataFrame([("count","doc_3",3), ("count","doc_2",6), ("type","doc_1",9), ("type","doc_2",6), ("one","doc_2",10)]).withColumnRenamed("_1","word").withColumnRenamed("_2","document").withColumnRenamed("_3","occurences")
```

From this I need to create the matrix like below:

```
----------+-----+------+----+
|document |count| type |one | 
+---------+-----+------|----+
|doc_1    |  0  |  9   | 0  |
|doc_2    |  6  |  6   | 10 | 
|doc_3    |  3  |  0   |  0 |
```

So I tried

```
print df.crosstab("document").show()
```

which didn't give what I wanted .Any help is appreciated

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to pivot Spark DataFrame?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30244910/how-to-pivot-spark-dataframe)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for [pivot](http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.2.1/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.GroupedData.pivot):

```py
df = sqlContext.createDataFrame([("count","doc_3",3), ("count","doc_2",6), ("type","doc_1",9), ("type","doc_2",6), ("one","doc_2",10)], ["word", "document","occurences"])
#document is the column you want to keep
#word is the columns which contains the rows which should become columns
#all other columns will be used as value for the new dataframe 
#a function like max() is required as wants to know what it should do if
#it has two rows with the same value for document and word
df = df.groupby('document').pivot('word').max()
df = df.fillna(0)
df.show()
```

Output:

```
+--------+-----+---+----+ 
|document|count|one|type| 
+--------+-----+---+----+ 
|   doc_1|    0|  0|   9| 
|   doc_3|    3|  0|   0| 
|   doc_2|    6| 10|   6| 
+--------+-----+---+----+
```