# DataBricks: Pivottable for spark dataframe

Tags: python, databricks

Suppose I have the following data frame

Year  Mon  value1   value2
2019  Jan   10       10
2019  Jan   20       20
2019  FEB   30       30
2019  FEB   10       10

I would like to pivot to :
Year  JAN_VALUE1    FEB_VALUE1   JAN_VALUE2  JAN_VALUE2
2019  30              40          30           40

Any method to achieve that .

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to pivot Spark DataFrame?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30244910/how-to-pivot-spark-dataframe)

Answer (score 2):

Here is my pyspark code to do this :

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import *
from pyspark.sql.types import *


values = [
  (2019,"Jan",10,10), 
  (2019,"Jan",20,20), 
  (2019,"FEB",30,30), 
  (2019,"FEB",10,10)
]

rdd = sc.parallelize(values)
schema = StructType([
    StructField("Year", IntegerType(), True),
    StructField("Mon", StringType(), True),
    StructField("value1", IntegerType(), True),
    StructField("value2", IntegerType(), True)
])

data = spark.createDataFrame(rdd, schema)

valu1Pivoted = data.groupBy("Year") \
                   .pivot("Mon") \
                   .sum("value1") \
                   .select(col("Year"), \
                           col("Jan").alias("JAN_VALUE1"), \
                            col("FEB").alias("FEB_VALUE1"))

valu2Pivoted = data.groupBy("Year") \
                   .pivot("Mon") \
                   .sum("value2") \
                   .select(col("Year"), \
                           col("Jan").alias("JAN_VALUE2"), \
                           col("FEB").alias("FEB_VALUE2"))

finalData = valu1Pivoted.join(valu2Pivoted, valu1Pivoted.Year == valu2Pivoted.Year, "inner") \
                  .drop(valu1Pivoted.Year) \
                  .select("Year", "JAN_VALUE1","FEB_VALUE1","JAN_VALUE2","FEB_VALUE2")
finalData.show(20,False)
```

Results :

```
+----+----------+----------+----------+----------+
|Year|JAN_VALUE1|FEB_VALUE1|JAN_VALUE2|FEB_VALUE2|
+----+----------+----------+----------+----------+
|2019|30        |40        |30        |40        |
+----+----------+----------+----------+----------+
```

Comment: @Michael Chau  Please upvote the answer if it worked for you.