# Spark pivot invokes Job even though pivot is not an Action

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

May be a silly question, but I note that:

```
val aggDF = df.groupBy("id").pivot("col1")
```

causes a Job to be invoked. Running under Databricks with Notebook. This is gotten:

```
(1) Spark Jobs
    Job 4 View     (Stages: 3/3)
       Stage 12:     8/8
       Stage 13:     200/200
       Stage 14:     1/1
```

I am not aware `pivot` is an Action from docs.

As per usual I cannot find a suitable reference in the docs to explain this, but there is likely be something to do with that `pivot` is seen as an Action or calls an aspect of Spark that is an Action.

Comment: Sharp distinction between action and transformation has been thing of the past for a while now (note that are not even mentioned in SQL docs, and only by accident in SS docs). And even before, many "transformations" where at least partially eager(ish). Pivot is a trivial example  (and already [covered by canonical thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35676755/10465355)), but all types of actions can be triggered when physical plan is generated (not that it is common in practice).

Comment: @10465355saysReinstateMonica  jsonny stuff as well, docs could be better.

Comment: Beyond basics, which are quite intuitive, such things are hardly something that can be documented - details are fuzzy, as depend on multiple moving factors, and most of the large deployments use some in-house modifications anyway.

Comment: @10465355saysReinstateMonica  Made your point

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are two versions of `pivot` in `RelationalGroupedDataset`.

If you pass only the columns, Spark has to fetch all the distinct values to generate columns, performing a `collect`.

The other method is more recommended but requires you to know in advance the possible values to generate columns.

You can take a look at the source code : https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/RelationalGroupedDataset.scala

```
def pivot(pivotColumn: Column): RelationalGroupedDataset
```

vs

```
def pivot(pivotColumn: Column, values: Seq[Any]): RelationalGroupedDataset
```

Comment: On. Cool. I have been triggered in my mind about your comment now.