# How to pivot a Pyspark Dataframe

Tags: dataframe, pyspark

I have the following challenge: I have a dataframe called hashtags_users_grouped which has the following structure:

```
hashtag_id  |  user_id  |  count
   123            1          1
   245            1          3
   123            2          5
```

In each row, we find values that tell me when a certain user mentioned a certain hashtag and how many times he did it. In this example, user 1 mentioned hashtag 123 one time and 245 three times, while user 2 only mentioned hashtag 123 five times.

I want to have a dataframe with the following output:

```
user  |     123  |          245
1            1               3
2            5               0
```

In other words, the same information as the first table, but with a column per hashtag, to know the amount of times a user mentioned each hashtag. I read the documentation and tried to run the following, without success:

```
a = hashtags_users_joined_grouped_df.groupBy("user_id").pivot("hashtag_id")
a.show(5)
```

I got the following error message:

```
AttributeError: 'GroupedData' object has no attribute 'show'
```

Do you know any way to do this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to pivot Spark DataFrame?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30244910/how-to-pivot-spark-dataframe)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After applying [`pivot`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.GroupedData.pivot.html) you need to perform an aggregate, in this case the aggregate is [`first`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.functions.first.html?highlight=first#pyspark.sql.functions.first) as the `count` metric has already been computed.

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

df = spark.createDataFrame([(123, 1, 1, ), 
                            (245, 1, 3), 
                            (123, 2, 5),], 
                           ("hashtag_id", "user_id", "count", ))

df.groupBy("user_id")\
  .pivot("hashtag_id")\
  .agg(F.first("count"))\
  .show()
```

### Output

```
+-------+---+----+
|user_id|123| 245|
+-------+---+----+
|      1|  1|   3|
|      2|  5|null|
+-------+---+----+
```