# How can I pivot in pyspark?

Tags: pyspark, databricks

How can I pivot this table?

Category sub category and month

How to make a pivot table in PySpark at databricks?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Mbyv.png)

I want 4 colum output:
Catageory, Subcatageroy, Months name, Sale
Appreciate yur help in my learning process.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to pivot Spark DataFrame?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30244910/how-to-pivot-spark-dataframe)